# Hide images programmatically in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xlabs

Is it possible to hide pictures taken by the camera or by choosing a file (I am creating a copy of it)?
Or do I have to change the file-extension of the picture, or will it then be rejected by Apple?

I am using XLabs for taking/selecting the picture

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'hide'?

Comment: Prevent it from showing up in Gallery apps

Comment: You can save it to your app's local storage without saving it to the gallery

Comment: But do it then not show up in the gallery?

Comment: No, it does not.  Lots of apps take pictures for their own use without saving them to the gallery.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I thought I have to do some specific like ".nomedia" in Android

Answer (score 0):

If you save it locally as an app data file then it shouldn't be then showed in the gallery.

So, to reiterate: Save the file as an app data-file.